# How to set guest user password on SAMBA server?

Tags: samba

I'd be generally ok with guest and an empty password as I don't need any access rights management among my users. But the server is a remote internet-accessed machine, so I'd prefer to set a good password for it. What's the most simple way? Can I just specify a password in samba.conf, or absolutely need to use LDAP or add users to the server system?

Comment: You shouldn't expose samba to the WAN side of your network just like that. Instead use a ssh tunnel or a VPN to connect to samba over WAN. If you do so, guest accounts don't matter any more than they do on a LAN.

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=217084

Make sure you set: `guest ok = yes` and `guest = guest` in smb.conf. Make sure SELinux isn't getting in your way while you are testing `setenforce 0`. You may also need `valid users = guest`

You would probably need to set the password for the guest user using `smbpasswd –a guest` as well (if user exists -a may not be needed.) Make sure to remember to restart samba. `service samba restart` (might be smbd restart can't remember off top of my head).

Comment: You don't need to restart samba, smbcontrol smbd reload-config will do.